# How do I compare 2 directories dir1 and dir2 and only copy differences in python?

Tags: python

Given 2 directories:

```
dir1
 |
 +----A
 |
 +----B

dir2
 |
 +----A (changed)
 |
 +----B (no change)
 |
 +----C (added)
```

I want to write a python script which will detect and make the following changes:

- copy C from `dir2` to `dir1`
- copy A from `dir2` to `dir1`

My idea is to obtain a md5 checksum for all the files. Am I going in the right direction ?

Comment: You are aware that you're reinventing `rsync`?

Comment: Can rsync work on local directories ?

Comment: Note there is also `unison` for bidirectional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the filecmp module.

http://docs.python.org/library/filecmp.html

It also has a function to [compare directories.](http://docs.python.org/library/filecmp.html#filecmp.dircmp)

```
class filecmp.dircmp(a, b[, ignore[, hide]])
```

Answer (score 1):

If the files are big then using MD5 checksums is certainly sane.

Make sure to check for the "modified" timestamps to always copy over the newest file.